# C++ callbacks from objects managed by std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a C++ project where I store objects in cells in a grid container. Every cell may contain one or zero objects stored in a std::unique_ptr. Naturally all methods having these objects as arguments should take a const std::unique_ptr reference to maintain the "uniqueness".

Secondly, when something happens to the objects they emit a signal with themselves as one of the arguments; these signals are caught by the grid container in a single handler (therefore we need the object reference). The handler may take some action on the object or emit its own signal, passing the object reference further.

The problem is that the objects themselves obviously cannot return a std::unique_ptr reference to themselves, while all other methods operating on them expects one. Is there a way to solve this, or do I have to let go of unique pointers and use raw ones?

Here's a code example using the sigc++ library (please allow for minor errors since I haven't tested it):

```
class Inhabitant
{
public:
  void sos()
  {
    signal_distress.emit (*this);
  }

  // Signals
  sigc::signal<void, Inhabitant &> signal_distress;
};

class Cell
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> set_inhabitant (std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> inhabitant)
  {
    // Set new inhabitant, return previous one...
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> m_inhabitant;
};

class Grid
{
public:
  void add_inhabitant_at (std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> inhabitant,
                          unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
  {
    // Connect the inhabitant to our rescue team
    inhabitant->signal_distress.connect (sigc::mem_fun (*this,
      &Grid::on_inhabitant_distress));

    // Place in cell
    m_cells[x][y].set_inhabitant (std::move (inhabitant));
  }

private:
  // Data
  Cell m_cells[100][100];

  // Helpers
  void help_inhabitant (const std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> &inhabitant)
  {
    // Do something helpful
  }

  // Signal handlers
  void on_inhabitant_distress (Inhabitant &inhabitant)
  {
    // Now, how do I call help_inhabitant(), or any other function that expects
    // a unique_ptr reference?
  }
};
```

Comment: Your design is too unclear. No idea how to answer that properly.

Comment: I prefer to pass parameters as either raw pointers or `shared_ptr`, depending on whether the object lifetime needs to be managed or not; `weak_ptr` is a possibility too. Passing `unique_ptr` causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But surely the whole point about unique_ptr is that you pass references to it, rather than a raw pointer? Otherwise you lose the whole uniqueness thing and it's just about garbage collection.

Comment: My point was that the choice of pointer type is related to the lifetime issue, nothing else. If a function is not keeping a copy of the pointer and doesn't need to worry about its validity, a raw pointer is the simplest and most flexible choice. Using a const unique_ptr reference doesn't give you any advantage except for avoiding a `.get()` in the function call, and as you've noticed it introduces awkward restrictions.

Comment: I can imagine lots of cases where you do want to keep copies of the pointer. Say we're making a board game and the grid container owns the pieces; the cells only have non-owning references to them. Then we add a separate listener object watching the state of one of the pieces. It's still a fairly simple setup, but apparently the pure unique_ptr-references-only concept doesn't work in these situations. Oh well.

Comment: The "pure unique_ptr-references-only concept" is fundamentally flawed and your insistence on it is the cause of your problems. If you stop trying to achieve that and use raw pointers for the non-owning references all your problems go away.

Answer (score 3):

It is a best practice not to pass smart pointers such as unique_ptr to functions that do not need to take (or share) ownership of the resource managed by the unique_ptr. Put another way, I don't think you would ever want to pass a unique_ptr by const reference. Instead, all the functions that are taking these unique_ptr references really only need to take a `const Inhabitant &`. For example:

```
void help_inhabitant (const Inhabitant &inhabitant) {
    // do stuff with the inhabitant directly
}
```

Comment: Agreed. `const unique_ptr&` or `const shared_ptr&` mean nothing, except 'I am burdening you with the useless knowledge of how these objects are allocated, but you cannot do anything with that knowledge'...! Obvious, but for completion, I'd mention that we pass to such functions from an owning `unique_ptr` like this: `help_inhabitant(*uptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Naturally all methods having these objects as arguments should take a const std::unique_ptr reference to maintain the "uniqueness".

No, the object still has a single unique owner, no matter how many other pieces of code can access it via non-owning pointers or references. Your idea that passing around `const unique_ptr<T>&` maintains any kind of invariant or enforces a policy is an illusion.

> Is there a way to solve this, or do I have to let go of unique pointers and use raw ones?

You don't have to give it up competely, just where it's inappropriate. Use `unique_ptr` for managing ownership and lifetime, use raw pointers for simply referring to an object that is managed by some other piece of code.

> surely the whole point about unique_ptr is that you pass references to it, rather than a raw pointer?

No, definitely not.

The `unique_ptr` manages the **ownership** of the object, but not doesn't have to be used for access to the object.

If you want to refer to the object without owning it then passing references or pointers to the object is fine (as long as the code receiving those pointers or references doesn't think it is taking ownership and try to delete the object). The code that just wants to use `Inhabitant` doesn't need to care that it is owned by a `unique_ptr`, it just wants to use the object. How its lifetime is managed is someone else's concern, and the code that doesn't own the object should not be made dependent on the ownership policy. Avoiding that dependency would allow you to change the owner to use `shared_ptr` or some other mechanism, and the signal handlers would be unaffected because they do not have to change how they access the object.

Pass a `unique_ptr` by value (or rvalue reference) to transfer ownership. Do not pass a `unique_ptr` by const-reference, because it's completely useless, the caller can't do anything with it that can't be done with a raw pointer.

Using a reference to a `unique_ptr` actually introduces a new class of bug that wouldn't exist otherwise:

```
void register_callback(func_type f, const unique_ptr<T>& obj);

unique_ptr<T> p(new T);
register_callback(func, p);   // stores reference to p
unique_ptr<T> p2 = std::move(p);
```

Now the signal handler still refers to `p` which is going to be empty when the callback happens. The *identity* of the `unique_ptr` is completely irrelevant, all that matters is that exactly one `unique_ptr` object owns the pointer, it doesn't matter which one owns it. But you have made the callback depend on the exact instance of `unique_ptr` by binding a reference to it, so you cannot move that (so you can never move a `Cell`, which means you can't store it in a container such as `vector` that might reallocate and move its elements)

If you do it this way instead the callback refers to the object, and it doesn't matter precisely where it's stored:

```
void register_callback(func_type f, T* obj);

unique_ptr<T> p(new T);
register_callback(func, p.get());   // stores p.get()
unique_ptr<T> p2 = std::move(p);
```

The callback's copy of the `p.get()` pointer remains valid even though ownership of it transfers from one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved the problem when I realized there is no reason why the cell inhabitants should send a reference to themselves with the signal. Instead the listener (the grid) can bind a reference to the inhabitant (the unique_ptr to it, that is) when registering with the signal:

```
inhabitant->signal_distress().connect (std::bind (&Grid::on_inhabitant_distress,
                                                 this,
                                                 std::cref (inhabitant));
```

This way the signal handler can take a unique_ptr:

```
void on_inhabitant_distress (const std::unique_ptr<Inhabitant> &inhabitant)
{
  // Now everything is fine!
  help_inhabitant (inhabitant);
}
```

and the "uniqueness" chain stays intact.

Comment: How would ownership of the pointer become any less unique if you gave a raw pointer to the signal handler? The only way that can happen is if the signal handler tried to take ownership of the pointer (either putting it in another `unique_ptr` or deleting it). So don't do that.

Comment: There is no '_"uniqueness" chain_'. There is only your misconception that passing things around by `const unique_ptr&` conveys any information, except the useless information of how the object is allocated, which the recipient can't do anything with and doesn't need. Also, now your handlers have UB if you move that `unique_ptr` somewhere else. Whereas if you bound a reference to the _contained object_, it would be valid forever, even persisting through moves into other `unique_ptr`s.